# Recommended convention for declaring record types for algebraic structures

Tags: inheritance, record, agda

I would like to contrast two styles for declaring new record types for algebraic structures in Agda.

Following the style used in the standard Agda package `Algebra`, one might define `BoundedJoinSemilattice` as follows:

```
record IsBoundedJoinSemilattice {a ℓ} {A : Set a}
                                (_≈_ : Rel A ℓ) (_∨_ : Op₂ A) (⊥ : A) : Set (a Level.⊔ ℓ) where
   field
      isCommutativeMonoid : IsCommutativeMonoid _≈_ _∨_ ⊥
      idem : Idempotent _≈_ _∨_

   open IsCommutativeMonoid isCommutativeMonoid public

record BoundedJoinSemilattice c ℓ : Set (suc (c ⊔ ℓ)) where
   infixr 6 _∨_
   infix  4 _≈_
   field
      Carrier : Set c
      _≈_ : Rel Carrier ℓ
      _∨_ : Op₂ Carrier
      ⊥ : Carrier
      isBoundedJoinSemilattice : IsBoundedJoinSemilattice _≈_ _∨_ ⊥

   open IsBoundedJoinSemilattice isBoundedJoinSemilattice public

   commutativeMonoid : CommutativeMonoid _ _
   commutativeMonoid = record {
         Carrier = Carrier;
         _≈_ = _≈_;
         _∙_ = _∨_;
         ε = ⊥;
         isCommutativeMonoid = isCommutativeMonoid
      }
```

With this approach, any fields of `BoundedJoinSemiLattice` that *overlap* (up to renaming) with those of other more abstract structures such as `Setoid`, `Semigroup`, `Monoid` and `CommutativeMonoid` are *duplicated* in `BoundedJoinSemiLattice`. In order to view a `BoundedJoinSemiLattice` as one of its "supertypes", one must call a projection function responsible for mapping its fields to those of the supertype, such as the `commutativeMonoid` function above.

However, this field duplication can lead to significant boilerplate in code that builds more specific algebraic structures out of less specific ones. A more natural definition might be something like this (renaming `CommutativeMonoid` to `CM`):

```
record IsBoundedJoinSemilattice {c ℓ} (cm : CM c ℓ)
                                      (⊥ : CM.Carrier cm) : Set (c Level.⊔ ℓ) where
   field
      isCommutativeMonoid : IsCM (CM._≈_ cm) (CM._∙_ cm) ⊥
      idem : Idempotent (CM._≈_ cm) (CM._∙_ cm)

   open IsCommutativeMonoid isCommutativeMonoid public

record BoundedJoinSemilattice c ℓ : Set (suc (c ⊔ ℓ)) where
   field
      commutativeMonoid : CM c ℓ
      isBoundedJoinSemilattice : IsBoundedJoinSemilattice commutativeMonoid (CM.ε commutativeMonoid)

   open CommutativeMonoid commutativeMonoid public using (Carrier; _≈_) renaming (
         _∙_ to _∨_;
         ε to ⊥
      )
   open IsBoundedJoinSemilattice isBoundedJoinSemilattice public
```

Here, the idea is not to duplicate the fields of `CommutativeMonoid` into `BoundedJoinSemilattice`, but rather for the latter to declare a single field of type `CommutativeMonoid`. We then use an `open...public` to "inherit" its sub-fields into the containing record. Indeed, this is exactly the idiom used elsewhere in the standard library in `Algebra.Structures`, except that here we also rename the inherited fields, so that they are appropriately named in the inheriting context.

Not only is this second approach less redundant, but now client code that wants to construct a `BoundedJoinSemilattice` from a `CommutativeMonoid` can simply pass it as an argument to the record being constructed. On the other hand, client code that wants to construct a `BoundedJoinSemilattice` from scratch must now construct an intermediate `CommutativeMonoid`.

Is there a reason that the `Algebra` module doesn't use this inheritance style, but  `Algebra.Structures` does? Maybe there are problems with the second approach that I haven't spotted, or perhaps it doesn't make much difference: for example with the first approach, maybe one can simply define a "constructor" function which handles the construction of a `BoundedJoinSemiLattice` from a `CommutativeMonoid`, to recover much of the convenience of the second approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem I see with the second approach is that you cannot compose ("inherit") more than one structure. Let me illustrate the point with `CommutativeSemiring`, the definition from `Algebra.Structures` requires two `IsCommutativeMonoid`s:

```
record IsCommutativeSemiring
         {a ℓ} {A : Set a} (≈ : Rel A ℓ)
         (_+_ _*_ : Op₂ A) (0# 1# : A) : Set (a ⊔ ℓ) where
  open FunctionProperties ≈
  field
    +-isCommutativeMonoid : IsCommutativeMonoid ≈ _+_ 0#
    *-isCommutativeMonoid : IsCommutativeMonoid ≈ _*_ 1#
    distribʳ              : _*_ DistributesOverʳ _+_
    zeroˡ                 : LeftZero 0# _*_

  -- ...
```

Now imagine we used your proposed solution. Here's how `IsCommutativeSemiring` would look like:

```
record IsCommSemiring {c ℓ}
  (+-cm : CommutativeMonoid c ℓ)
  (*-cm : CommutativeMonoid c ℓ) : Set (c ⊔ ℓ) where
  open CommutativeMonoid +-cm
    using (_≈_)
    renaming (_∙_ to _+_; ε to 0#)
  open CommutativeMonoid *-cm
    using ()
    renaming (_∙_ to _*_; ε to 1#)
  open FunProps _≈_

  -- more stuff goes here
```

And now you are in serious trouble: you have no idea what the the `Carrier`s of the respective `CommutativeMonoid`s are, but they better be the same type. So you already have to make this ugly step:

```
record IsCommSemiring {c ℓ}
  (+-cm : CommutativeMonoid c ℓ)
  (*-cm : CommutativeMonoid c ℓ) : Set (suc (c ⊔ ℓ)) where
  open CommutativeMonoid +-cm
    using (_≈_)
    renaming (Carrier to +-Carrier; _∙_ to _+_; ε to 0#)
  open CommutativeMonoid *-cm
    using ()
    renaming (Carrier to *-Carrier; _∙_ to _*′_; ε to 1#′; _≈_ to _≈′_)
  open FunProps _≈_

  field
    carriers : *-Carrier ≡ +-Carrier
```

And then, with the help of `subst`, you must define `_*_` which works in `+-Carrier`:

```
  _*_ : (x y : +-Carrier) → +-Carrier
  _*_ = subst (λ A → A → A → A) carriers _*′_
```

And finally, you can write the field for distributivity:

```
  field
    distribʳ : _*_ DistributesOverʳ _+_
```

This looks very awkward already, but it gets worse: the underlying equalities should be same as well! This might not seem to be a huge issue at first, you can just require `_≈_ ≡ _≈′_` (well, `_≈_ ≡ subst (λ A → A → A → Set ℓ) carriers _≈′_` in fact), but when someone tries to use the proofs, they're in for a surprise. You might also be surprised that you can, in fact, be the first person to use those proofs. Looking at `IsCommutativeSemiring` from `Algebra.Structures`, we find this code:

```
  distrib : _*_ DistributesOver _+_
  distrib = (distribˡ , distribʳ)
    where
    distribˡ : _*_ DistributesOverˡ _+_
    distribˡ x y z = begin
      (x * (y + z))        ≈⟨ *-comm x (y + z) ⟩
      ((y + z) * x)        ≈⟨ distribʳ x y z ⟩
      ((y * x) + (z * x))  ≈⟨ *-comm y x ⟨ +-CM.∙-cong ⟩ *-comm z x ⟩
      ((x * y) + (x * z))  ∎
```

If you tried to write that with your version, you'd have `subst` all over the place. The only thing you can do at this point is to rewrite all proofs that use `_≈′_` into their `_≈_` form (again, tons of `subst`s) - and this raises a question: is it still worth it?

---

Considering your idea with "constructor" function: this is certainly doable. But then again, you'll run into issues when you want to compose more than one structure.

Here's how you can make a `Monoid` from a `Semigroup`:

```
semigroup→monoid : ∀ {c ℓ} (s : Semigroup c ℓ) →
  let open Semigroup s
      open FunProps _≈_
  in (ε : Carrier) (identity : Identity ε _∙_) → Monoid c ℓ
semigroup→monoid s ε id = record
  { Carrier = Carrier
  ; _≈_ = _≈_
  ; _∙_ = _∙_
  ; ε   = ε
  ; isMonoid = record
    { isSemigroup = isSemigroup
    ; identity    = id
    }
  }
  where
  open Semigroup s
```

Actually, `isSemigroup` uniquely determines most of the record (`Carrier`, `_≈_` and `_∙_`) and `id` also determines `ε`, so we can even write:

```
semigroup→monoid s ε id = record
  { isMonoid = record
    { isSemigroup = Semigroup.isSemigroup s
    ; identity    = id
    }
  }
```

Which is actually very concise.

Comment: Thanks again for an excellent answer. Yes, carrying around (and having to rely on) a proof that the two carriers are equal (for your example) sounds messy. Is this essentially due to the existential nature of record types? I ran into a similar issue trying to implement `Functor` for a data type of tries over a commutative monoid supplied as a `CommutativeMonoid` rather than an `IsCommutativeMonoid` - I didn't have a way to obtain the function of type `Set → Set` for the `Functor` instance, because the carrier was buried in the `CommutativeMonoid`.

Comment: Anyway, your `semigroup→monoid` function is an example of the boilerplate I was trying to avoid, but it looks innocuous compared to the business with `subst`. More important, your second version of `isSemigroup` introduces an Agda feature I wasn't aware of, which pretty much makes the boilerplate issue go away :)
Finally, I've also learnt that I can put a `let...in` inside a function signature! Good stuff, thanks again.

Comment: @Roly: Yes, sometimes you just need that structure which is parametrized over the carrier (and probably the equality) but the operations are hidden inside the record. The question is then where do you draw the line? Do you expose just carrier + equality and keep the rest hidden? What if the structure has more than one relation (some partial order, for example), or what if you need it to be parametrized over that one operation. I think the library gives a fair choice: the explicit, more granular definition (`IsSomething`) and the usual mathematical one (a set with operations).